# How disable a Tab for all application?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, .net-5

Is there a simple solution to disable navigation of any graphical elements via Tab-button and in any attachments? That is, it is simple to "deactivate" this button while the application is running, and not to prescribe `element.IsTabStop = true` for all app's elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Input_KeyboardNavigation_TabNavigation) attached property to `None`.

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
```

This applies to the children of the control that it is attached to as well.

> Gets or sets the logical tab navigation behavior for the children of the element that this property is set on.

However, you will have to set it on all top-level elements, e.g. windows. Dependending on your specific scenario, you might be able to create a common style to apply it.